# How to remove all roles from a member apart from one discord.js v12?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I would like to have a command that removes all roles from a member apart from one specific role. For now, I've made it so it removes all roles and then adds the one I want to keep with a delay, but if someone has a lot of roles, it removes the one I want to keep too. My code:

```
member.roles.remove(member.roles.cache).catch(error => {
  message.reply(`failed to remove roles of <@${member.id}>, try moving at least one of my roles above all of the other ones`)
  return
});

antagReason.split('')

setTimeout(() => {
  member.roles.add(antagonistRoleID)
  .then(memberAdded => {
    message.reply(`you have succesfully antagonized <@${member.id}> with the reason **${antagReason}** <:AliasAntag:757173746925830165>`);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}, 200);
```

Is there a way to remove all the roles apart from one? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of removing every role and then adding one back, just use [`GuildMemberRoleManager.set()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=set)

```js
member.roles
 .set([antagonistRoleID])
 .then((memberAdded) => {
  message.reply(
   `you have succesfully antagonized <@${member.id}> with the reason **${antagReason}** <:AliasAntag:757173746925830165>`
  );
 })
 .catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
 });
```